# VBA - how to create multiple Chart Sheets, one for each series

Tags: excel, vba, loops, variables, charts

i'm new at coding with VBA and could use your help!

i have the following data set. I have a lot of regions, and i want to display the data of each region separately in an own Chart-Sheet.

| Year | Region1 | Region2 | Region3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 10 | 60 | 70 |
| 2018 | 20 | 50 | 80 |
| 2019 | 30 | 40 | 90 |

The following simple code allows me to create the expected Chart Sheet, but only for one data Series: the one in Sheet("Data_Source").Range(B1:B8).

```
Sub Add_Chart_Tab()
    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Set MyChart = Charts.Add
            With MyChart
                .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data_Source").Range("B1:B8")
                .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Data!$A$2:$A$8"
            End With
End Sub
```

I tried an alternative code, which provides me with what I want, except that 1) the charts are all stashed one over the other in the same sheet, and 2) these are charts but not Chart Sheets. In the code above I would like to set the Range in the Source ("B1:B8") as variable Cells (like in the code below, with i and j), but every time I try, I get an error message that this method is not supported.

```
Sub AddCharts()

    Dim i As Integer ' rows
    Dim j As Integer ' columns

    i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 2 To 4

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    
            With .SeriesCollection(1)
        
                .Name = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Cells(1, j).Address
                .XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(i, 1)).Address
                .Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(i, j)).Address
        
            End With
    End With
    Next j    
End Sub
```

My objective is to combine the two codes:

1. Create multiple Chart-Sheets, not normal charts
2. Loop through the data series in order to display in each chart sheet the data of one region

**Can somebody help me?**

Answer (score 0):

The parameter (`SetSourceData`, `XValues`) for the chart has the potential to be a dynamic `Range` object.

Microsoft reference document:

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub AddCharts()
    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Dim i As Integer, Dim j As Integer 
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Set Sht = Sheets("Data")
    i = Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 2 To 4
        Set MyChart = Charts.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            With MyChart
                .SetSourceData Source:=Sht.Cells(2, j).Resize(i - 1, 1)
                .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sht.Range("A2").Resize(i - 1, 1)
                .Name = Sht.Cells(1, j)
            End With
    Next j
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

```
Sub Add_Chart_Tabs()
  Dim XVals As Range
  Set XVals = Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:A8")
  Dim iChart As Long
  For iChart = 1 To 3 ' or however many
    Dim YVals As Range
    Set YVals = XVals.Offset(, iChart)
    Dim SrsName As Range
    Set SrsName = YVals.Offset(-1).Resize(1)
    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Set MyChart = Charts.Add
    With MyChart
      Dim iSrs As Long
      For iSrs = .SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
        ' remove any series created by default
        .SeriesCollection(iSrs).Delete
      Next
      With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Values = YVals
        .XValues = XVals
        .Name = "=Data!" & SrsName.Address
      End With
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```